# Error: Failed to submit prompt, the text content is empty with trained model

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I created a tuned model using Gen AI Studio's "Create tuned model". When I try to test it with "Model Registry > {Name of the model} > Version" and clicking "Open in prompt design" under "Test your model", I only get an error telling me "The text content is empty." while I sure have text in the content.

One noteworthy thing is that I'm not allowed to choose any model from the model dropdown.

Here's screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image]

I'm expecting to be able to test my model.

Comment: Hi @Niklaus, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.<br>